# MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptProtectData'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Help me resolve this error when I run my ASP.NET project.

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptProtectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
```

when I use  for login in my project .net 6, cannot load layout, help me.

[image]

Login.cshtml

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="yourUsername" name="username"/>
            <div id="ErrorEmail" style="color: red;" class="form-text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Mật Khẩu</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="yourPassword" name="password" />
            <div id="ErrorPassword" style="color: red;" class="form-text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" id="Btn_Login" type="submit">Đăng Nhập</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

AccountController

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password, string ReturnUrl)
{
    if ((username == "Admin@gmail.com") && (password == "Admin"))
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Login");

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
        return View();
}
```

I hope to get a good solution

Comment: Is your target project settings Core 7?

Comment: This happens when you use a Nuget package that requires .NET7 in a web app that targets .NET6.  Use an earlier version of the package to fix.  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45149

Answer (score 1):

Check the .NET Core version you are using and ensure that all NuGet packages in your project are compatible with this version. For example if you use .Net6 your  packeges must not be version 7.0 etc. and make sure all packages are of the same version.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the mismatch between the versions of the installed packages and the target framework of the project.
you can set target to .net 7 and update your installed packages.

Comment: So now you basically copied what other people said in their answers already months ago (April & June), not very original

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, this question and topic helped me alot,
I was setting the cookie authentication in my .net project and in one major methods for this purpose,same exception raised, the method was HttpContext.SignInAsync()

so after reading this topic I started to check my entire solution packages, in every layer and more precisely in every class librery (or projects of my solution), I went to my related project csproj to see packages, but there was no problem and all versions of packages was suitable for .net 6, but in related layer there was project reference to another layer, and in that layer there was package:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="8.0.0" />
```

with visual studio package manager, I tried to install one of the previous version of this package, and in downgrading steps,this messege appeared:

Uninstalling:

System.ComponentModel.Annotations.5.0.0

Updates:

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.6.0.0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.6.0.0**
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores.6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.6.0.0

Installing:

System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.6.0.0

as you can see in messege, this package was related to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography which could not match .net 6, and after version downgrade, the exception disappeared.
so in your case i guess you have package that is causing the exception, the package that affected Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography version and made it incompatible with your ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 0):

Translate the target platform in the project properties to .net 7

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).